# Can't edit/delete top row in uitableview - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Not sure why but the top row of my uitableview is not editable, all other rows function as normal and delete as expected. It's like caneditrowat indexPath: Indexpath isn't working for that one row. See images attached.

My code in tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:) looks like all the tutorials I can find, can't seem to find any other examples with this problem.

```
//MARK: Properties
    var favouriteExercises = [FavouriteExercise]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Load exercises from local DB
    if let savedFavouriteExercises = loadFavouriteExercises()
    {
        //loading exercises in from the favourites
        favouriteExercises += savedFavouriteExercises
    }

    // Use the edit button item provided by the table view controller.
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //count number of rows in table
    return favouriteExercises.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "FavouriteTableViewCell"

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? FavouriteTableViewCell  else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of FavouriteTableViewCell.")
    }

    // Fetches the appropriate exercise for the data source layout.
    let exercise = favouriteExercises[indexPath.row]

    //setup the layout for the cell in the table view
    cell.nameLabel.text = exercise.name
    let url = URL(string: (exercise.iconUrl))!
    cell.photoImageView.sd_setImage(with: url)
    //cell.photoImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "defaultPhoto")
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

    return cell
}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        favouriteExercises.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        saveFavouriteExercisess()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: The only possible way might be => func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle { if indexPath.row == 0 { return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.none} return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete}.

Comment: Thanks very much @KumarReddy! Used your solution without the if statement and it worked.

Comment: Make my comment as helpful:) and up vote

Answer (score 1):

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
    }
```

Answer adapted from @KumarReddy's solution